# How to restrict a div stay at the bottom of another 2 div

Tags: html, css

I got 3 div with 33% width.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
</div>
```

How can I restrict the 3rd div not to align with the other 2 divs, I want the first 2 div in a row and the 3rd div bottom side using CSS properties??

Comment: Do you want to keep same width of three divs ?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem through a solution below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the third div to appear on the next line, or "bottom side", then just give it `block` level display, like so:

```css
.col-md-4 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.block {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 block">3</div>
</div>
```

If this is not what you want then please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is my simple solution. I use CSS Grid in the following code.

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">Text One</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Text Two</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Text Three</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.row div:last-child {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
</div>
```

solution:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" style="display: inline-block;">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="display: inline-block;">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this at your css

```
.col-md-4{
  width:33.33%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.col-md-4:nth-of-type(3){
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap, it's easy to achieve this as all you need to do is it exceed the `12 cols for a row` concept.

Just add `col-md-12` to your last div.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">a1</div>
  <div class="col-4">a2</div>
  <div class="col-12">a3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
</div>
```

Solution:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
 <div class="col-md-5">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 text-center"> Col-4 </div>
  <div class="col-6 text-center"> Col-4 </div>
  <div class="col-12 text-center"> Col-12 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="display:inline-block;" class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;" class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div style="display:block;" class="col-md-4">a</div>
</div>
```

Set style of first 2 divs to display:inline-block; and 3rd one to display:block;

Working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vwbtg1fp/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
<style>
    .col-md-4{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: burlywood;
        border : 1px solid black;
    }


</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
</div>
```